# Method based linq queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have five tables in database whose Entity classes are as follows -

**Product**

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Category { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Brand { get; set; }
public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ProductVariantMapping> ProductVariantMappings
```

**ProductCategory**

```
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

**ProductImage**

```
public int ProductImageId { get; set; }
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

**ProductVariantMapping**

```
public int MappingId { get; set; }
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public System.Guid GUID { get; set; }
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
public virtual ProductVariant ProductVariant { get; set; }
```

**ProductVariant**

```
public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ProductVariantMapping> ProductVariantMappings
```

I want to get Product Details which should include ProductId, ProductName, Category, Description, Brand, Image(Only 1 for now), and **Variants***

***Variants would be a list of all the variants of a product. A single variant can be a combination of all the VariantIds with same GUIDs. (VariantName is in ProductVariant table and VariantValue is in ProductVariantMapping table and Price is in inventory table).**

So, I used method-based linq for this purpose.

```
EkartEntities ekartEntities = new EkartEntities();

var productDetails = ekartEntities.Products.Include(p => 

  p.ProductVariantMappings).Include(p => p.ProductImages).Include(p =>

  p.ProductCategory).Where(p => p.ProductId == 

  productDetailDTO.ProductId).ToList();
```

Now I have to convert my product into a ProductDetailDTO.

**ProductDetailDTO**

```
public class ProductDetailDTO
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I started doing this like this -

```
    void ToDTO(List<Product> products)
    {
        EkartEntities ekartEntities = new EkartEntities();
        ProductDetailDTO productDetailDTO = new ProductDetailDTO();
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            productDetailDTO.ProductId = item.ProductId;
            productDetailDTO.Name = item.Name;
            productDetailDTO.Category = item.ProductCategory.Name;
            productDetailDTO.Description = item.Description;
            productDetailDTO.Brand = item.Brand;
            productDetailDTO.Image = item.ProductImages.ElementAt(0).Image;
            foreach (var variant in item.ProductVariantMappings)
            {
                productDetailDTO.Variants = variant.ProductVariant // ?
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how do I proceed further. How can I extract the variant based on the GUIDs?

Comment: Did you mean you wanted to group the ProductVariantMappings by its GUID?

Comment: Please add the inventory table and its relation with ProductVariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of combining of `ProductVariant` entries with same `GUID` in mapping table doesn't seem clear from the question, however you can group entries in `ProductVariantMappings` by `GUID` and then add any logc you like on group. Here is an example where I take first name and value in a groub of variant with the same `GUID`:

```
void ToDTO(List<Product> products)
{
    EkartEntities ekartEntities = new EkartEntities();
    ProductDetailDTO productDetailDTO = new ProductDetailDTO();
    foreach (var item in products)
    {
        productDetailDTO.ProductId = item.ProductId;
        productDetailDTO.Name = item.Name;
        productDetailDTO.Category = item.ProductCategory.Name;
        productDetailDTO.Description = item.Description;
        productDetailDTO.Brand = item.Brand;
        productDetailDTO.Image = item.ProductImages.ElementAt(0).Image;

        productDetailDTO.Variants = item.ProductVariantMappings
            .GroupBy(pm => pm.GUID)
            .Select(g => new Variant
            {
                Guid = g.Key,

                // Here should be some logic for getting a name of the combination of Variants
                // I just take first
                Name = g.FirstOrDefault()?.ProductVariant?.Name,

                // Here should be some logic for getting a value of the combination of Variants
                // Take first again
                Value = g.FirstOrDefault()?.Value,

                Price = // need inventory table to compute price
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Also note that you need somehow add relation to inventory table, which is not presented in question. Hope it helps.